# C++ using clang-tidy with external libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, clang, clang-tidy, clangpowertools

I'm first time user of clang-tidy. I am working on my thesis using OpenCV.
My issue is that when I configure clang-tidy to "Fix" the issues it finds, it will fix the issue it finds in the OpenCV library as well.
My question is: how can I make it so that clang-tidy only fixes the issues it finds in the files created by me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Messing around with the clang power tools options I found that setting `Treat additional includes as` to `system include directories` fixes my problem.